# How can I choose groups in fcitx5 with the Hotkeys (Linux\KDE)

Tags: kde-plasma, fcitx

I have to use several different keyboard setups with fcitx5 in KDE environment.
Is there a way to bind the different groups selection to hotkeys. (I want to get the Windows-like behavior: "Ctrl+Shift+1 -- select Group 1", "Ctrl+Shift+2 -- select Group 2", "Ctrl+Shift+3 -- select Group 3").

fcitx5 allows to switch groups with "Win+Space", be it seems no way to select a particular group directly.